# Current USB C smartphones with 5000mah around $400 comaprable to Honor 8?

Tags: smartphones

I've found Honor 8X Max with 5000mah capacity and almost ordered it but then found out it has no USB-C so slow charging.

What are most close alernatives, that is not much more expensive but 4-5 Ah and USB Type C?

Comment: Fast charging isn't limited to USB-C.

Comment: Also, the device supports fast charging:  https://www.gsmarena.com/honor_8x_max-9306.php

Comment: What does this mean?